# RestKit PUT not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit, http-put

I'm trying to do a fairly basic HTTP PUT using RestKit. I don't want to put the entire object, since the API call was designed to accept a single query parameter and just update that field. I've tried two approaches so far, both unsuccessful.

URL to post to: `https://myserver/api/users/{userId}`

Query string parameter: `verificationCode=`

Example usage: `PUT https://myserver/api/users/101?verificationCode=646133`

Approach #1: Put the query parameter in a RKParams object and make the PUT call with those params.

```
    NSString *putUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/users/%i", [APIUserInfo sharedAPIUserInfo].apiUserIdx];
    NSLog(@"the PUT url is %@", putUrl);

    // Send a PUT to a remote resource. The dictionary will be transparently
    // converted into a URL encoded representation and sent along as the request body
    NSDictionary* paramsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[_verificationCode text] forKey:@"verificationCode"];
    // Convert the NS Dictionary into Params
    RKParams *params = [RKParams paramsWithDictionary:paramsDict];

    [[RKClient sharedClient] put:putUrl params:params delegate:self];
```

Approach #2: Build the entire url and try a PUT with params set to nil.

```
    NSString *putUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/users/%i?verificationCode=%@", [APIUserInfo sharedAPIUserInfo].apiUserIdx, [_verificationCode text]];
    NSLog(@"the PUT url is %@", putUrl);

    [[RKClient sharedClient] put:putUrl params:nil delegate:self];
```

Neither approach is working for me.  The first fails saying "RestKit was asked to retransmit a new body stream for a request. Possible connection error or authentication challenge?" then runs for about 10 seconds and times out. The second approach fails saying HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong, or provide me with a simple PUT example using RestKit? Most of the examples I've found at there are putting the entire object which I don't want to do in this case.

---

**UPDATE:**

Approach #2 worked well once I got a few things sorted out on the server side. Final solution:

```
NSString *putUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/users/verify/%i?verificationCode=%@", [APIUserInfo sharedAPIUserInfo].apiUserIdx, [_verificationCode text]];
NSLog(@"the PUT url is %@", putUrl);

[[RKClient sharedClient] put:putUrl params:nil delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the HTTP PUT method is disabled on your webserver.  It is by default on all webserver for security reasons.

```
HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed.
```

Comment: I'll talk to the backend guys. Can you comment as to which approach I should use?

Comment: Im not a rest expert but if you are going to use rest I think you just have to enable PUT on the server and you should be good.  There are security implications but your backend guys will have to work that out with you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I talked to them and they found a security config problem on their side they are resolving. As far as the __how__ I believe approach 2 is correct. I'll update when I get the final implementation working.